# FaceApi.js - Loading models in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, face-api

I have downloaded models folder inside my project (project/src/app/pages/tests/models) and I trying to load the files in my page Tests (src/app/pages/tests), but when compiled,the following error appear in console:

[image]

Code with models loading:

```
  async ngOnInit() {
    Promise.all([
      await faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('./models'),
      await faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('./models'),
      await faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('./models'),
      await faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('./models')
    ]).then(() => {
      this.startVideo();
    })
  }
```

Is something wrong with my models calling?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the models folder in the static folder

```
in vuejs -> /static
in react -> /public
in angular -> /src
```

and then

```
await faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
await faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
await faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
await faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try loading your models from within the `assets` folder. And call them as (assuming they're in the `models` subdirectory, i.e. `assets/models`:

```js
Promise.all([
  faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('assets/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('assets/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('assets/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('assets/models'),
]).then(startVideo);
```

NB: There is also really no need to `async-await` your `faceapi.nets` calls since they are in a promise call and nothing will execute before it finishes.